# Get the ID of a new listItem and update same record

Tags: sharepoint-addin, app, client-object-model, sharepoint-hosted-app

I'm trying to add a new record and get the new ID created then use the new ID to create a specific reference number using the following code.

```
function saveDraftGHrecord() {
ghList = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Listname');
var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
ghItem = ghList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
ghItem.set_item("ReasonOther", $('#txtReasonOther').val());
etc
etc

ghItem.update();
context.load(ghList);

context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
    // Success returned from executeQueryAsync
    //Now we need to get the new ID and add that to ref.
    var newID
    newID = ghItem.get_id();
    //alert(newID);
    ghList = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Listname');
    ghNewItem = ghList.getItemById(newID);
    context.load(ghNewItem);
    ghNewItem.set_item("FieldName", "REF" + newID);
    ghNewItem.update();
    context.load(ghNewItem);
    cancelNewRecord();
}),
function (sender, args) {// Failure returned from executeQueryAsync
    alert("Failure " + args.get_message());
}

}
```

The Record is being added an I am getting the newID using ghItem.get_id() but i cant seem to then update the same record with the new REF using ghNewItem.set_item("FieldName", "REF" + newID);

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You don't need to get the object of the newly created item again as `ghNewItem`  since it is already loaded as `ghItem` .
2. You need another executeQueryAsync call at the end

   ```
   function saveDraftGHrecord() {
   ghList = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Listname');
   var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
   ghItem = ghList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
   ghItem.set_item("ReasonOther", $('#txtReasonOther').val());
   etc
   etc

   ghItem.update();
   context.load(ghList);

   context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
       // Success returned from executeQueryAsync
       //Now we need to get the new ID and add that to ref.
       var newID
       newID = ghItem.get_id();

       ghItem.set_item("FieldName", "REF" + newID);
       ghItem.update();
       context.load(ghItem);
       context.executeQueryAsync(function () {},function () {})
       cancelNewRecord();
   },
   function (sender, args) {// Failure returned from executeQueryAsync
       alert("Failure " + args.get_message());
   });

   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

After setting the REF field content and instructing the content to load it, you need to call the executeQueryAsync method again.